# Installing PHP Project Wizard (PPW) using the PEAR Installer

Tags: php, continuous-integration, phpunit, pear

I am trying to install PPW using PEAR installer on Windows.I`m executing in CMD:

```
pear install phpunit/ppw
```

and I`m getting this error message:

```
 No releases available for package pear.phpunit.de/ppw install failed
```

I follow all the steps in this [tutorial](https://github.com/edorian/php-project-wizard#php-project-wizard-ppw), but I`m still getting the same error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is from 2011, and things have changed in the meantime. Sebastian Bergmann probably removed the package from `pear.phpunit.de`.

Comment: I stopped maintaining php-project-wizard around 2011 and `pear.phpunit.de` does not exist anymore either.

Comment: @SebastianBergmann any recommendation on a replacement script? i am trying to setup a CI with jenkins, zend and github and so far most tutorials include this script as one of the steps needed to achieve that goal.